# Why Does the Google Sheet API and Google Drive API consume so much memory upon requests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, task-queue, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheet API to write into the Google Sheet and generate a salary slip, while I use the Google Drive API to download the sheet as pdf.. But I have been encountering a major with this, which had to do with this:

> Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 155 MB after servicing X requests total

Below is my code:

```
class GenerateSalarySlip(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):

    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    self.response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"

    response = {'status': 'ERROR',
                'message': 'ERROR!!'}

    try:
        credentials = AppAssertionCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http(timeout=120))

        # Create a communication between my app and google api endpoint
        SHEETS = build('sheets', 'v4', http=http_auth)

        # Original Spreadsheet Template
        template_spreadsheet_id = template_spreadsheet_id 

        # Sheet Id for companies
        m_sheet_id = '0'
        k_sheet_id = '1'
        f_sheet_id = '2'

        # Get the current month and year as Salary Slip TItle
        this_month = time.strftime('%B')
        this_year = time.strftime('%Y')
        month_year = this_month + ' ' + this_year
        # title = month_year + ' Salary Slip'


        new_spreadsheet_id = new_spreadsheet_id

        # Copy the template sheet to the new monthly spreadsheet
        copy_to_body = {"destinationSpreadsheetId": new_spreadsheet_id}

        # Copy M Sheet
        mkr = SHEETS.spreadsheets().sheets().copyTo(spreadsheetId=template_spreadsheet_id, sheetId=m_sheet_id,
                                                    body=copy_to_body).execute()

        # Copy K Sheet
        ktvr = SHEETS.spreadsheets().sheets().copyTo(spreadsheetId=template_spreadsheet_id, sheetId=k_sheet_id ,
                                                     body=copy_to_body).execute()

        # Copy F Sheet
        fgr = SHEETS.spreadsheets().sheets().copyTo(spreadsheetId=template_spreadsheet_id, sheetId=f_sheet_id,
                                                    body=copy_to_body).execute()

        # Start a Loop using the Payroll Month query filter
        mon_yr = time.strftime('%b') + '-' + time.strftime('%y')
        # mon_yr = self.request.get('mon_yr')

        payroll_info = Payroll.query(StaffPayroll.month_year == 'Sep-16').fetch(20)

        # Sheet Index count
        i = 4
        for pi in payroll_info:

            # Set memcache for the Payroll Object from the Datastore
            memcache.set(pi.payroll_id, pi, 7200)  # expires after 2 hrs

            # Employee's employment information
            ei = pi.staff_employment_history_info.get()

            staff_info = pi.staff_info.get()
            # Set memcache for the Staff info from the Payroll Object from the Datastore
            memcache.set(staff_info.staffID, staff_info, 7200)  # expires after 2 hrs

            company = ei.company
            company = company.strip()

            p_info = datastore_queries.get_personal_info(pi.staff_email)  # get Staff Personal info
            # Set memcache for the Personal Information Object from the Datastore
            memcache.set(p_info.nric_no, p_info, 7200)  # expires after 2 hrs

            rem_pk = datastore_queries.get_staff_remuneration_package(pi.staff_email)  # get Staff Rem Package info
            # Set memcache for the Remuneration package Object from the Datastore
            memcache.set(rem_pk.remuneration_id, rem_pk, 7200)  # expires after 2 hrs

            if company == 'M':

                # Duplicate template sheet, name new sheet after the staff name
                duplicate_salary_slip_sheet(SHEETS, mkr['sheetId'], i, staff_info.staff_name, new_spreadsheet_id)

                # Handle the Data Written into the Google Sheet
                bodys = input_data(pi, staff_info, p_info, rem_pk, month_year)

                # API to write and update Google Sheet
                SHEETS.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=new_spreadsheet_id, body=bodys).execute()

                # Create New Spreadsheet for Download
                # Copy the staff sheet into this new spreadsheet for download
                copy_to_ss_res, created_ss_id = create_new_spreadsheet_for_download(SHEETS, staff_info.staff_name, new_spreadsheet_id, i)

                # gc.collect()
                # Create Task Queues to Download the Spreadsheets and send as PDF mails to staffs
                taskqueue.add(params={'spreadsheet_id': created_ss_id,
                                      'filename': staff_info.staff_name + '.pdf',
                                      'staff_email': pi.staff_email,
                                      'mail_subject': staff_info.staff_name + ' Salary Slip for ' + month_year},
                              url='/hrms/taskqueues/google_drive/manage')

                gc.collect()


            i += 1

            response = {'status': 'OK',
                        'message': 'COMPLETED!!'}

    except Exception, e:
        logging.info(" *****Error from GenerateSalarySlip :")
        logging.exception(str(e))

    self.response.write(json.dumps(response)) 

# API to Manage the Google Drive API and Mail API and Task Queue
# Google Sheet file is Downloaded as pdf with Google Drive API
# Mail API sends the downloaded file as an attachment
# Task Queue Schedules when to do all these
class ManageGoogleDriveAPI(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):

    try:
        credentials = AppAssertionCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http(timeout=120))

        # Create a communication between my app and google api endpoint
        DRIVE = build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

        spreadsheet_id = self.request.get('spreadsheet_id')
        filename = self.request.get('filename')
        mail_subject = self.request.get('mail_subject')
        staff_email = self.request.get('staff_email')

        request = DRIVE.files().export_media(fileId=spreadsheet_id, mimeType='application/pdf')

        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)

        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            logging.info("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

        mail.send_mail(sender='project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'.format(
            app_identity.get_application_id()),
                       to="example@mail.com",
                       subject=mail_subject,
                       body="""
Attached is your Salary Slip for the Month.

""",
                       attachments=[(filename, fh.getvalue())])

        DRIVE.files().delete(fileId=spreadsheet_id).execute()

        # gc.collect()

        logging.info('COMPLETED Google Drive!!')

    except Exception, e:
        logging.info(" *****Error from ManageGoogleDriveAPI :")
        logging.exception(str(e))
```

I don't understand why it is saying am exceeding the memory usage.. I really want to know what is consuming the memory in the google apis am using because when commented out the google sheet api code lines and task queue, the application ran successfully without memory leak or consumption... Please, can someone help with this..

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. The other question is "What is the "soft private memory limit" in GAE?". This question, on the other hand, is specific to why Google Sheets API and Google Drive API consume so much memory to the point that it triggers a soft private memory limit error? Can you please re-open? I also have the same concern, and it would be nice to see this answered. Thanks!

Comment: @Albert Thank you for your comment. According to my research, i found out that there is limit to the number of requests you can make with the Sheets API. And as for the memory leak, it is because of the number of calls to the Sheets API on just one instance. So, I resolved this by created another Service on my GCP Project to specifically handle what I want to do with the Sheets API and I increased the RAM to 512MB..